# Need to remove a line in fstab on OpenBSD

Tags: fstab, openbsd

I thought it would be easier for me to mount flash drives automatically if I did the following to fstab:

```
/dev/sd1i /mnt/usb
```

(sd1i is found from sysctl hw.disknames)

I rebooted the box with the USB 3.0 flash drive still inserted in the USB 3.0 port.

During the boot process, the following errors were detected:

```
/dev/rsd1i: BAD SUPER BLOCK: MAGIC NUMBER WRONG
/dev/rsd1i: Unexpected inconsistency: Run fsck_ffs manually
The following file system had an unexpected inconsistency: ffs: /dev/rsd1i (/mnt/usb)
Automatic file system check failed; help!
Enter pathname of shell or RETURN for sh:
```

I checked out the article "How to use ed to edit /etc/fstab in single user mode" (http://www.openbsdsupport.org/ed_and_fstab.html) which discussed about how to use `ed` to modify lines but not to delete them.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Only being able to modify is also fine.  You can just comment out the offending line by putting a `#` in front of the bad line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `ed` unless you *really* want to.

Once you're at a single-user prompt (just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the `Enter pathname of shell or RETURN for sh:` prompt, do the following:

1. Mount the root filesystem as read-write, then mount the `/var` and `/usr` filesystems (this will allow you to run `vi` or any other editor of your choice)

   ```
   # mount -uw /
   # mount /var
   # mount /usr
   ```
2. Once those are mounted, edit `/etc/fstab` and remove the offending line.
3. Reboot.

   ```
   # reboot
   ```

Your system should then restart correctly in multi-user mode.

Comment: 1st question - `mount -uw /` What does it do? I thought the command to mount the root filesystem is `mount /dev/wd0a /` (wd0a is obtained from `sysctl hw.disknames`)? 2nd question - Does the command `mount /dev/wd0a /` mount the root filesystem as *read-write*?

Comment: @virvegto It remounts the root filesystem read/write. If you don't specify a device node to mount (eg, `/dev/wd0a`), the device will be looked up in `/etc/fstab` and that entry used. Yes, by default mount writes filesystems read/write.

Comment: Just to feedback, I'd to mount a 16-alphanumeric label with a file extension of `a` as in y53z7bpv6givj4nb.a as follows: `mount y53z7bpv6givj4nb.a /`. Ditto for the other partitions. After mounting the partitions that I needed, I'd to `export TERM=vt220` first before I could use an editor to edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @virvegto You shouldn't normally have to mount each filesystem in `fstab` by entering the device node or disklabel unique identifed, (DUID, the 16 character string you mentioned), but I'm guessing you had to because you had an invalid entry in `fstab`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did have an invalid entry in `fstab`.